# Why I have only one album?

Tags: python, django

I'm started learning Django and there are some problems with it:)
This is views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Album


def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for album in all_albums:
        url = '/music/' + str(album.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href ="' + url + '">' + album.album_title + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

There is class Album. 
This is models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

I created two albums(for example "Red" and "Destiny" and I want my albums with references appears on page http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/ . But there is only one album "Red". I think that my loop "for" doesn't working, but I can't understand why. 
I hope you'll understand my question.
Help me please, I want to sleep :)

Comment: Use an `__init__` method to initialize your albums so that each album is a different object. Also, how are you creating your Album objects?

Comment: try add `print (str(album.id))` is it real two times?

Comment: I created in admin panel

Comment: did you try print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any way, please override your code in pythonic style, and may be it help

```
def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    html = []
    for album in all_albums:
        url = '/music/%s/' % album.id
        html.append('<a href ="%s">%s</a><br>' % (url, album.album_title))
    return HttpResponse(''.join(html))
```

for detail read [join docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

and by comment of @Björn Kristinsson string params by `%` it is older method, better solution is

```
def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    html = []
    for album in all_albums:
        url = '/music/{id}/'.format(id=album.id)
        html.append('<a href ="{url}">{title}</a><br>'.format(url=url, title=album.album_title))
    return HttpResponse(''.join(html))
```

Comment: If we're going down that path it may also be worth noting that % is the older method which may or may not be deprecated in the future. The recommended method is using format, something like `url = '/music/{}'.format(album.id)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting

Comment: Thank you, this is working! But I can't understand why my code is not working. What is means `''.join(html)` ?

Comment: glad to help. You should accept the answer to let future searchers know it solved your problem. And about joun i added description to the answer.